# Is there a way to change environment settings of a dataset without creating a new one?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I am trying to change the environment settings of an existing dataset. 
I found a workaround by first changing the environment settings in the SDE-database and then create a new dataset with now correct settings. Now I copy&paste my features from the old to the new dataset. But I guess copying is rather dangerous because some database information might be lost? So I would like to avoid it.
The values I would like to change are:
XY-Tolerance
XY-Resolution
Z-Tolerance
Z-Resolution
Z-min.Domain
M-Tolerance
M-Resolution
I am aware that with changing these values the features will grow/shrink/move a tiny bit.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may be going about this the wrong way.  You should probably create a new feature class, specifying all the spatial reference properties that you want, and importing the fields from your source class.  Then load the data from your source class to your destination class.

You aren't going to be able to just change those values without actually having to reload the data.  The values from the Domain and Resolution (I think this is the same as scale?) are used when compressing the geometry.  This is why you are seeing your data grow/shrink/move.  You may be able to get away with changing the Tolerance values, but I wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: After a day of testing I think this really is the best way to do it! In my SDE-geodatabase I now create a new dataset with the new properties and then import all the features from the old to the new dataset. Thank you for your help!